# Summation and product convention

Tags: convention, index-notation

Is there a standard convention for iterated addition or product when the upper index is smaller than the lower index? That is, how to expand these terms:
$$
\sum_{i=a}^b x_i, \\
\prod_{i=a}^b x_i
$$
when $b < a$.

Comment: When I see something like that it usually refers to the empty sum (value $=0$) or the empty product (value $=1$), but in other contexts there might be different conventions